# accordion fixed height with sortable list inside

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion, jquery-ui-sortable

i have an accordion with accordion content height 280px. Inside i have a sortable list connecting with another that sits outside the accordion (right).

When the contents of the accordion is more than 280px displays the scroll down.

So far so good.

The problem is when scroll is displayed when i start drag an element from sortable list to the left connecting sortable list the accordion content overflow at x-axis displaying the horizonta scroll and make the movement difficult. You have to keep move the drag element enough in order to move out accordion and sits to the sortable list at left.

I searched almost  anywhere and trying to make correction regarding overflow at accordion contents but no solution found.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .ui-accordion-content{
        overflow:visible !important;
    }
</style>
```